# Should I install the Desktop image or the Server image if I need both

Tags: server, system-installation, samba

This seems like the kind of question that should be in a FAQ somewher, but I could not find it.
(please point me to the correct place if it is already out there)

I am setting up a machine for a home office. I want it to be a file server for all machines and laptops in the family, but it will also be my primary desktop. The machine is an old, but fairly beefy PC (single quad core Intel CPU and plenty of disk space and memory).

So the question is should I install the Server image and add a GUI to it, or should I install the Desktop image directly? Does the desktop image include things like DNS and Samba?

Thanks for any advice,

Doug.

Answer (score 5):

**It doesn't matter.**

Ubuntu Desktop is Ubuntu with some extra desktop packages.

Ubuntu Server is Ubuntu with some extra server packages.

You can add server packages to Desktop. You can add desktop packages to Server. It's all Ubuntu.

**Advice**:

- Most new users find it easiest to install Ubuntu Desktop, and add some server packages to it.
- Ubuntu Desktop includes Samba ("File Sharing")
- Ubuntu Desktop does not include a DNS server. Most small networks don't require a DNS server -- if yours does, there's a package for it.